# vServer blocked by Cloudflare (solve captcha on console)

Tags: php, server, putty, cloudflare, blocked

Need some Ideas,I worked with an external API(Path of Exile) and accidently reached the max. request limit so my vServer is now blocked (by Cloudflare). 
When i now want to access the api I get the following

> "One more step Please complete the security check to access
>   www.pathofexile.com"

ecetera ecetera then in theory the Google Captcha comes.

Problem is that I need a graphical Browser to solve the captcha/security check, right ? What would be the best solution to solve the captcha now ?
I was thinking about some way of tunneling my own Browser and pretending to be the server, is that possible ? If yes what Keywords to google would help.

Or would anyone suggest an even simpler solution that would work only on the console ? Or with a simple php script like (file_put_contents in a temp. file and then putting that in an iframe but beforehand replacing some urls/paths ?)

I guess the Problem is not in the code, but here it is

```
$realm = "pc";
$league = "Standard";
$uiagent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/32.0.1700.107 Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36';
$poeurl = 'https://www.pathofexile.com/character-window/get-stash-items?league=' . $league . '&realm=' . $realm . '&accountName=' . $_COOKIE["accountname"] . '&tabs=0&tabIndex=' . $_GET['no'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $poeurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $uiagent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'POESESSID'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'/var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXX.de/www/html/poe/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "POESESSID=b34637XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/var/www/vhosts/XXXXXXXXX.de/www/html/poe/cookie.txt');
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $answer;
    file_put_contents(getcwd() . "/cache/" . $_COOKIE["accountname"] . "/stash-" . $_GET['no'] . ".json", $answer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly solved it

Alright, hope it will help someone some day.
Here is how I solved my problem.

Since I had SSH access via putty, I changed my connection settings in Firefox to use my putty tunnel through the server, that way the targeted API got the IP from the server when I accesed it in FireFox and I could solve the Captcha, surprisingly simple. Here one blogpost how to do it:
https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2013/01/using-firefox-with-a-putty-ssh-tunnel-as-a-socks-proxy/

Comment: Unfortunately the website does not exist anymore.